# fail to connect R with InfluxDB (status code 404)

Tags: r, influxdb

I was trying to connect R with InfluxDB and had trouble getting my result. I used `influxdb_query(host, port, username, password, dbname,query)` as in https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb-r/blob/master/R/influxdb.R and got this error:
*Influx query failed with HTTP status code 404*.

Does anyone know what the problem is? Thanks in advance.

Sophie

Comment: Which value did you give to `host` and `port`?

Comment: Hi @Pascal,host is '52.26.122.126' and port is 8086. url is like: "http://52.26.122.126:8086/query?u=xxx&p=xxx&db=xxx&q=xxx"

Comment: Are you sure you provided valid host? 404 error is "page not found".

Answer (score 0):

The R library was written to work with prior versions of InfluxDB (likely the 0.7.x family). If you are running InfluxDB 0.9.x it will not be compatible. There are breaking changes to the query language between the versions.

The R library looks fairly abandoned at this point, with no updates for nearly a year. I do not know when it will be updated to work with InfluxDB 0.9.